Old black and white movie/TV show with lobsters committing suicide
A man and a woman are having an argument in a kitchen, where there is a pot of boiling water on the stove and a number of live lobsters next to it. The man says to the woman, "It's not my job to commit murder!" The camera cuts to a close-up of the lobsters, which voluntarily begin walking into the pot of boiling water, accompanied by comical marching music.
I saw this brief scene from a film or possibly TV programme while changing between TV channels. On British terrestrial daytime TV, round about 2002-2006.
Characters are white, speaking English with probably an English (RP) accent but it could have been American - I can't remember. Live action, shot in black and white, style/quality seemed indicative of the 1950s or so. It's been 20 years since I saw it so my memory may not be completely accurate!
If anyone could identify this, that would be amazing. Google has revealed nothing remotely like it.

Live action or animated?

Live action - now edited.

@tehziyang - If it was live action, then how did they film the lobsters lining up to commit suicide?

The pot in the close up shot was not really boiling and they just poked them from behind to get them moving? Or they could have been fake/puppet lobsters for all I remember.
